# Systemd BindPaths= not working

Tags: debian, systemd, bind-mount

I am trying to test how the `BindPaths=` directive works on a Debian 8 system with systemd.

Currently I have a basic unit file for a service:

```
[Unit]
Description="Simple Test Service"
BindPaths=/path:/bindmount/path:norbind

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/long_running_program --flags
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `findmnt` before and after starting the service I do not see the bind mount at `/bindmount/path` listed at all.

When I `ls` or `ls -a` the bind mount location `/bindmount/path` I do not see any files that are in `/path`.

**Why is this not working as expected?**

I [see in the systemd BindPath= man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#BindPaths=) it says:

> This option is only available for system services and is not supported for services running in per-user instances of the service manager.

How do I know if I am running in a per-user instance of the service manager vs running a system service? Is it based on if my service is located in `/etc/systemd/system` vs `/lib/systemd/system`?

Answer (score 0):

The `BindPaths` option make the file visible to the process ran by the unit. This is not visible at all from the shell where you type the command to start the service. At any moment you may check what file systems are mounted looking at `/proc/mounts`, but if you run a service with BindPaths, I think the only way to check if the file system is correctly mounted is to check `/proc/`*pid-of-service*`/mounts`. The latter is the list of mounted file system for that process.

About your final questions: `/lib/systemd/system` contains all normal unit files, while `/etc/systemd/system` contains custom unit files and all dependencies between units. Per user instances are run with `systemctl --user` and refers to unit files in the home directory tree.

Comment: I do not see them in /proc/PID/mounts as well. :(
`BindPaths=/etc/node/confs/.apt:/etc/node/.apt/confs`

Comment: Might it be that you are running it as user service? What do the commands "systemctl status yourserviceunitname" and "systemctl --user status yourserviceunitname" print?

Comment: `Failed to connect to bus: $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not defined (consider using --machine=<user>@.host --user to connect to bus of other user)`.  I do specify the user and group I create to run the service.

Comment: What is the *complete* pathname of your unit file? What is the *exact* and *complete* command line you use for starting it?